# ip address output how to interpret it?

Tags: ipv6

I'm on Fedora Silverblue 36

I'm with an Italian provider called "Fastweb"

This is the output of ip address show

```
$ ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ... brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:7a:91:c4:71:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.51/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 78520sec preferred_lft 78520sec
    inet6 2001:b07:a3e:3d82:1c4a:1094:d08b:8ba4/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 85931sec preferred_lft 85931sec
    inet6 fe80::d9da:1206:fe2c:c73f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I see the ipv6 is split in 2 parts

why ?

In the GUI I only see one ipv6 address

Also I see "valid_lft" and "preferred_lft"

"lft" is obviously an acronym

What does it stand for ?

Comment: lft indicates the lifetime of the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

so

one is an address local to my home network

another one is global

also the GUI does show 2 distinct addresses, I made a mistake